# I want to concatenate n files but the concatenation is not in correct order?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program to concatenate N files which I should read them from the keyboard and then take all of their concent starting from FILE1 to n and put them on a NEWFILE, my program concatinates all of the N files but the order is not from 1 to n. For example:

```
I input N=3 and I put three files:
text1.txt (inside the file I have "We cannot")
text2.txt ("live")
text3.txt ("without water.")
and then save the concatination on a finalresult.txt
```

Now my finalresult.txt should be:

```
We cannot
live
without water.
```

But my result is:

```
withoutwater. We cannot live
```

Here is my full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    int i;

    char a[number][50];
    char help[50];
    for(i=0; i<number; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", help);
        strcpy(a[i], help);
    }

    printf("Concating the content of %d files ...\n", number);

    FILE * filer, * filew;
    int numr,numw;
    char buffer[64];

    for(i=0; i<number; i++)
    {

        filer = fopen(a[i], "rt");
        if(filer == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "open read file error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        filew = fopen("finalresult.txt","a+t");
        if(filew==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"open write file error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while(feof(filer)==0) {
            numr=fread(buffer,1,100,filer);

            if(numr!=100) {

                if(ferror(filer)) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"read file error.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            numw=fwrite(buffer,1,numr,filew);

            if(numw!=numr) {
                fprintf(stderr,"write file error.\n");
                exit(1);
            }

        }
    }

    fclose(filer);
    fclose(filew);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move `fopen = fopen("finalResult.txt", "a+t")` *OUTSIDE* of the for loop?  Just open it once, then write to it for each output file.  ALSO: make sure your `fclose()` statements all match the corresponding `fopen()`.

Comment: `I am trying to write a C program to concatenate` -> `cat FILE1 FILE2.... > OUT` ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 I actually did not think about that, and yes it works now haha, thanks

Comment: also make sure to move the `fclose(filer)` inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite this

```
char a[number][50];
char help[50];
for(i=0; i<number; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", help);
    strcpy(a[i], help);
}
```

as

```
char a[number][50];
for(i=0; i < number; ++i)
    scanf("%s", a[i]);
```

you don't need another intermediate buffer. Also bear in mind, that `"%s"`
matches only non-empty characters, if your filename has an empty character,
`scanf` won't read the whole input and leave behind extra characters in the input
buffer, thus messing with the next `scanf` call. Here it would be better to use
`fgets`.

```
char a[number][50];
for(i = 0; i < number; ++i)
{
    if(fgets(a[i], sizeof a[i], stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read the filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    a[i][strcspn(a[i], "\n")] = 0; // removing newline
}
```

I haven't seen the mode `'t'` for `fopen`, is that a an extension of the modes
for Windows?

A problem with your code is that you are calling

```
filew = fopen("finalresult.txt","a+t");
```

inside the loop but you never close it inside the loop. `FILE* file` is buffered,
that means when you use `fprintf(file,...)` or `fwrite(..., file)`
the content gets buffered and the content is physically written in the file at a
later point, for example when the buffer is full or you use `fflush(filew)`. So
when you `fopen` the same file before doing a `fflush` or `fclose`, the old
buffered content remains in the buffer and is written at a much later point (in
your case when the program exits), thus overwriting your new content. Your new content
will have the same fate. At the end you end up with a mess because the content
gets overwritten at the end of the program. That's why you see "garbage" in the
file.

So, you have to do `fclose` before doing `fopen` with the same filename, or
better you should do the `fopen` before the loop.

Also this check is incorrect:

```
if(numr!=100) {
    if(ferror(filer)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"read file error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

This would only be correct, if the file size is a multiple of 100. If it's not,
the last block will have less than 100 bytes and you would end your program,
even though the `fread` had no errors.

So I'd rewrite your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t num_of_files;
    printf("Enter the number of files: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if(scanf("%zu", &num_of_files) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read the number of files\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int c;
    // clearing the input buffer
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    char fnames[num_of_files][50];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num_of_files; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the filename %zu: ", i+1);
        fflush(stdout);

        if(fgets(fnames[i], sizeof fnames[i], stdin) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not read the filename\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        fnames[i][strcspn(fnames[i], "\n")] = 0; // removing newline
    }


    FILE *filew = fopen("finalresult.txt", "wt");
    if(filew == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file finalresult.txt for writing: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < num_of_files; ++i)
    {
        FILE *filer = fopen(fnames[i], "rt");
        if(filer == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s for reading, skipping: %s\n",
                    fnames[i], strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }

        char buffer[100];
        size_t len;
        while((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, filer)) != 0)
        {
            if(fwrite(buffer, 1, len, filew) != len)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error writing finalresult.txt\n");
                fclose(filer);
                fclose(filew);
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        if(!feof(filer))
            fprintf(stderr, "file %s could not be read completely\n", fnames[i]);

        fclose(filer);
    }

    fclose(filew);

    return 0;
}
```